Cors error: strict-origin-when-cross-origin. How do I defeat this
I recently moved from my IISExpress development server to IIS 8.5. Now I am getting this CORS error. All configuration has been set correctly in the code, ASP.NET Core.
Here is my program.cs and my controller:
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Negotiate;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System.Diagnostics;
using WebApplication2.App_Contexts;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
ILoggingBuilder loggingBuilder = builder.Logging.AddConsole();
loggingBuilder.SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Debug);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddCors(opt =>
{
    opt.AddDefaultPolicy( policy =>
        {
            policy.WithOrigins("http://localhost:3000")
            .AllowAnyHeader()
            .AllowCredentials()
            .AllowAnyMethod();
        });
});

builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddDbContext<DEV_IntranetContext>();
builder.Services.AddDbContext<PreAuthContext>();

// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(NegotiateDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
   .AddNegotiate();

builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    // By default, all incoming requests will be authorized according to the default policy.
    options.FallbackPolicy = options.DefaultPolicy;
});

var app = builder.Build();

app.UseStaticFiles();
//app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseCors("CORS");

app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    context.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    context.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS");
    context.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Accept, Authorization");

    if (context.Request.Method == "OPTIONS")
    {
        context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.OK;
        await context.Response.WriteAsync("OK");
        return;
    }

    await next();
});

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("ContentRootPath", builder.Environment.ContentRootPath);
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("WebRootPath", builder.Environment.WebRootPath);

app.MapControllers();
app.Run();

SitemapController.cs:
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using WebApplication2.App_Contexts;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using WebApplication2.App_Linq;

namespace MCA.Controllers
{
    [EnableCors("AllowAllOrigins")]
    [ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    public class SitemapController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly DEV_IntranetContext _db;

        public SitemapController(DEV_IntranetContext db)
        {
            _db = db;
        }

        [EnableCors("AllowAllOrigins")]
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<string> Get()
        {
            var map = Data.Sitemap(_db);
            var sitemap = JArray.Parse(map);
            string? name = MCA.APIUtilities.GetName(HttpContext);

            if (name is not null)
            {
                var user = await new User(name, _db).Initialize();
                var roles = user.Roles.ToList();

                var data = new
                {
                    sitemap,
                    user = new
                    {
                        user = user.Name,
                        roles = string.Join(",", roles).ToLower()
                    }
                };

                var ret = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);
                return ret;
            }
            else
            {
                var data = new
                {
                    sitemap,
                    user = ""
                };

                return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);
            }
        }
    }
}

I have gone through every tutorials in page I can find. So far as I can tell the code is set up correctly. The calling app is React, but curl doesn't succeed either.
Thanks

I'm not seeing a "AllowAllOrigins" policy there.  Maybe just use [EnableCors].   Wildcarding origins (Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*" ) Is also not allowed when credentials are sent, so you might check that as well.  The "app.Use(async (context, next) =>..." stuff should probably be removed.  These headers are only sent back in response to pre-flight (OPTIONS request).

Yeah. I've been messing with a lot of stuff trying to figure it out. The "*" was part of that. I will try removing those other items also. Thanks.
edit. I tried what you suggested, no success. Same "strict-origin-when-cross-origin" on the header. Preflight works fine though.

technically "strict-origin-when-cross-origin" is not an error.  It just restricts the referrer header to domain only (when cross-origin).   That's just user-agent stuff.

so it'd prevent leaking params... ex: a link to your site comes from http://www.google.com/search?q=sensitive_search_term  Your site would only see google.com, and not the rest.

It's an intranet site, not accessible to the outside world. There is only one URL requests can be coming from. Hence the (right now) localhost:3000

if you do see an error, include that.  CORS errors are usually pretty explicit.  You should know that localhosts with different ports are treated as different domains. (so cross-origin).   Looks like domain-level negotiate here, so you can get the user just by doing something like:  username = User.Identity.Name;

I'm off until the new year so won't be able to reply until then.

strict-origin-when-cross-origin is related to the Referrer Policy. It's got nothing to do with CORS. You may suffer from a CORS error, but strict-origin-when-cross-origin has nothing to do with that.
